# What happens if I use `new` upon invoking a non-constructor function?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I'm working on a piece of legacy code and found a snippet looking like this:

```
const createError = function(msg) {
  return new Error(msg);
};

//...

const error = new createError('Something bad happened');
```

I see `error` actually gets the return value of `createError` so it seems that the `new` keyword has no effect in this case. But how does it actually work?

Comment: No the new keyword is working. You are creating a new `Error object`. If you `console` the `error` object, you can see that the tracestack prints that the `function` `createError` has an `Error`. `Error: Something bad happened
    at new createError (<anonymous>:2:10)
    at <anonymous>:7:15`

Comment: There's no "non-constructor" functions in JS (excluding some  exotics and arrow functions). Any function can be called with `new` operator, and when doing so, the function returns an object. If the value to return is not an object, it is ignored and the newly-created object is returned instead.